# Initialize pydantic Literal from array of strings

Tags: python, pydantic

I would like to inizialize a pydantic Literal from an array of strings

```
from typing import Literal
from pydantic import BaseModel

CLASS_NAME_VALUES = ["primary", "secondary", "success", "danger", "warning", "info", "dark"]
ICON_NAME_VALUES = ["electricity.svg", "water.svg",
                    "internet.svg", "naturalGas.svg", "noCategory.svg"]

class CategoryRequest(BaseModel):
    class_name: Literal[CLASS_NAME_VALUES]
    icon_name: Literal[ICON_NAME_VALUES]
```

But I am getting the following error

```
  File "pydantic/main.py", line 252, in pydantic.main.ModelMetaclass.__new__
  File "pydantic/fields.py", line 309, in pydantic.fields.ModelField.infer
  File "pydantic/fields.py", line 271, in pydantic.fields.ModelField.__init__
  File "pydantic/fields.py", line 351, in pydantic.fields.ModelField.prepare
  File "pydantic/fields.py", line 529, in pydantic.fields.ModelField.populate_validators
  File "pydantic/validators.py", line 566, in find_validators
  File "pydantic/validators.py", line 410, in pydantic.validators.make_literal_validator
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

At runtime, an arbitrary value is allowed as type argument to `Literal[...]`, but type checkers may impose restrictions. For example, `mypy` permits only one or more literal `bool`, `int`, `str`, `bytes`, `enum` values, `None` and aliases to other `Literal` types. For example, `Literal[3 + 4]` or `List[(3, 4)]` are disallowed.

As for `pydantic`, it permits uses values of hashable types in `Literal`, like `tuple`. For example, your sample could be rewritten using `tuple` as:

```
from typing import Literal
from pydantic import BaseModel

CLASS_NAME_VALUES = ("primary", "secondary", "success", "danger", "warning", "info", "dark")
ICON_NAME_VALUES = ("electricity.svg", "water.svg",
                    "internet.svg", "naturalGas.svg", "noCategory.svg")


class CategoryRequest(BaseModel):
    class_name: Literal[CLASS_NAME_VALUES]
    icon_name: Literal[ICON_NAME_VALUES]
```

But I would strongly advise against using this syntax, but sticking to the [canonical](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0586/#id23) one, which is also allowed by the type checkers:

```
CLASS_NAME_VALUES = Literal["primary", "secondary", "success", "danger", "warning", "info", "dark"]
ICON_NAME_VALUES = Literal["electricity.svg", "water.svg",
                    "internet.svg", "naturalGas.svg", "noCategory.svg"]


class CategoryRequest(BaseModel):
    class_name: CLASS_NAME_VALUES
    icon_name: ICON_NAME_VALUES
```

Comment: would there be any chance you could help me with this question on Pydantic? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72858080/pydantic-recursive-models