# Pydantic Recursive Models

Tags: python, pydantic

I am refencing the answer on this other [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65675648/initialize-pydantic-literal-from-array-of-strings) on using the Typing library `Literal` to specify a unique array to strings to validate the data with Pydantic but I am running into a problem of calling another class recursively.

This is what my code looks like:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, PydanticValueError, ValidationError, validator
from typing import Literal,Optional


ACTION_TYPE_MAPPING = Literal["read", "write", "release"]

OBJECT_TYPE_MAPPING = Literal["multiStateValue", "multiStateInput", "multiStateOutput",
                       "analogValue", "analogInput", "analogOutput",
                       "binaryValue", "binaryInput", "binaryOutput"]

BOOLEAN_ACTION_MAPPING = Literal["active", "inactive"]


# MAIN MODEL
class BacnetRequestModel(BaseModel):
    action_type: ACTION_TYPE_MAPPING
    object_type: OBJECT_TYPE_MAPPING
    object_instance: int
    value: Optional[ValueModel(object_type)]  <---- MESSED UP HERE, how to call ValueModel?


class ValueModel(BaseModel):
    multiStateValue: Optional[int]
    multiStateInput: Optional[int]
    multiStateOutput: Optional[int]
    analogValue: Optional[int]
    analogInput: Optional[int]
    analogOutput: Optional[int]
    binaryValue: Optional[BOOLEAN_ACTION_MAPPING]
    binaryInput: Optional[BOOLEAN_ACTION_MAPPING]
    binaryOutput: Optional[BOOLEAN_ACTION_MAPPING]



test = BacnetRequestModel(action_type="write",
                        object_type="binaryOutput",
                        object_instance="3",
                        value = "active"
                          )
```

How do I call the class `ValueModel` based on the `objectType` that was inputted to the function where in this case it was `binaryOutput` that should only accept a value of `BOOLEAN_ACTION_MAPPING`. Any tips help not a lot of wisdom here...

Traceback is:

```
    value = Optional[ValueModel(object_type)]
NameError: name 'ValueModel' is not defined
```

Comment: Maybe you mean `value: Optional[ValueModel]` and `test = BacnetRequestModel([...],                       value = ValueModel(binaryOutput="active"))`

Comment: Okay I fixed the `= :` typo in the class. But does this look right? `test = BacnetRequestModel(["write","binaryOutput","3"],value=ValueModel(binaryOutput="active"))`?

Comment: Sorry I use [...] as just placeholder, try to use `test = BacnetRequestModel(action_type="write", object_type="binaryOutput", object_instance="3", value = ValueModel(binaryOutput="active"))`

Comment: If I just comment out where I had the mistake of `: =` like `#value: Optional[ValueModel]` it works else if it is not commented out I get a     `value: Optional[ValueModel]
NameError: name 'ValueModel' is not defined`

Comment: I could probably just run with `#value: Optional[ValueModel]` or removing it from the `class BacnetRequestModel`

Comment: Thanks for your help if you post an answer ill hit green check box

Comment: you have to make ValueModel a string exg,: sfor: List[Union[str, "Stage"]] = Field(alias="for")  ... Stage is defined later, same is working for recursive types.